# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setSize(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

```
package design.nxn.login_template_01;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;


import java.text.BreakIterator;

import java.util.Objects;


import design.nxn.login_template_01.Tools.CustomViewPager;

import design.nxn.login_template_01.Tools.ViewPagerAdapter;


public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = BaseActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 420;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    private String personPhotoUrl;

    GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    BreakIterator mStatusTextView;

    private static final int LOGIN_FRAGMENT = 0;

    private static final int SIGNUP_FRAGMENT = 1;

    private static final int RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT = 2;

    private Fragment newFragment;

    private CustomViewPager viewPager;

    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        btnSignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        initializeGPlusSettings();

        initializeControls();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);



        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    }

    private void initializeControls() {

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


            }

        });

    }


    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        GoogleSignInAccount account = 
GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        updateUI(account);

    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

            handleSignInResult(task);

        }

    }

    private void handleGPlusSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        Log.d(TAG,"handleSignInResult:" +result.isSuccess());

        if (result.isSuccess()){

            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            String personname = acct.getDisplayName();

            personPhotoUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(acct.getPhotoUrl()).toString();

            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("personname",personname);

            intent.putExtra("email",personEmail);

            intent.putExtra("personphotoUrl",personPhotoUrl);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

        }

    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {

        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

            updateUI(account);

        } 

catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.

            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());

            updateUI(null);

        }

    }


    private void initializeGPlusSettings() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.

 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();

        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);



    }

    private void changeFragment(int fragmentType) {

        switch (fragmentType) {

            case LOGIN_FRAGMENT:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

                break;

            case SIGNUP_FRAGMENT:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(SIGNUP_FRAGMENT);

                break;

            case RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT);

                break;

            default:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

                break;

        }


    }

    public void signUpClick(View view) {

        changeFragment(SIGNUP_FRAGMENT);

    }

    public void signInClick(View view) {

        changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

    }

    public void resetPasswordClick(View view) {

        changeFragment(RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT);

    }

    public void backClick(View view){

        changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

    }

    @Override

    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == LOGIN_FRAGMENT)

            super.onBackPressed();

        else {

            changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

        }

    }

    public void logInButtonClicked() {

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.login_button_click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void signUpButtonClicked() {

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.signup_button_click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void resetPasswordButtonClicked() {

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.reset_password_button_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override

    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) 

   {

    }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {

     switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.sign_in_button:

                signIn();

            case R.id.logout:

                signOut();

                break;

        }


    }

    private void signOut() {

        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // ...

                    }

                });

    }

    private void revokeAccess() {

        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // ...

                    }

                });

    }




    private void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


    }


    private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        if (account != null) {

            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            findViewById(R.id.logout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } 

    else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(String.valueOf(R.string.signed_out));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         findViewById(R.id.logout).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting click here

```
switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.sign_in_button:

                signIn();
```

As per this code you need to use

```
 btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Instead of

```
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: changes done. but my app is crashing after USB debugging

Comment: What is the issue in debugging and is it work fine without debugging

Comment: error is:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: use this in your gradle   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

Comment: i have added sign in  with Google button in my project's login screen.before adding Sign in with Google button my project was run successfully.but after adding that button my app crashed.

Comment: Follow this tutorial or match your code with [this  tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

Comment: I have already added above  these  two dependecies in my gradle file(project gradle file)

Comment: Thank you so much for this Tutorial link.